# How do I get the data from "#PCDATA" in Scala?

Tags: xml, scala

```
def loadXml(node: Node): Unit = {

  val children = node.child

  children.foreach(child => {
    var tag = child.label

    //if owner tag, load the owen
    if (tag == "zip")
    {
      loadZipXML(child)
    }
    else if (tag == "owner")
    {
      //if owner tag, make a new pet and have it load the info it wants, then add it to the list
      val owner = Owner()
      owner.loadXml(child)
      insurance += owner
    }
  })
}
```

I have the following code and I'm feeding it this XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<insurance>
    <zip code="57701">
        <owner name="Harold">
        </owner>
        <owner name="Bob">
        </owner>
        <owner name="Indiana Jones">
        </owner>
        <owner name="Darth Vader">
        </owner>
    </zip>
    <zip code="57702">
        <owner name="Sue">
        </owner>
        <owner name="Captain Kirk">
        </owner>
    </zip>
    <zip code="57703">
    </zip>
</insurance>
```

I can pull the zip code fine. But every time I get owner the label becomes #PCDATA. I know that means that its a child with more data, but how do I grab that label and then keep traversing the XML file?

Comment: You forgot to include the `import` statement that informs the compiler, and the reader, which XML library you're using.

Comment: Would that be   "import scala.xml._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need the XML label, but it sounds like you're trying to marshal the data in to an "owner" data structure.  For example, consider this "owner" class:

```
final case class Owner(
  label: String, 
  name:  String, 
  text:  String, 
  zip:   String)
```

I'd probably iterate through the XML as:

```
val insurance = scala.xml.XML.load("insurance.xml")
val owners = 
  for {
    zip   <- insurance \ "zip"
    owner <- zip \ "owner"
  } yield {
    Owner(
      label = owner.label, 
      name  = owner \@ "name",
      text  = owner.text.trim,
      zip   = zip \@ "code"
    )
  }
```

Printing the file:

```
owners.foreach(println)
```

Outputs:

```
    Owner(owner,Harold,,57701)
    Owner(owner,Bob,,57701)
    Owner(owner,Indiana Jones,,57701)
    Owner(owner,Darth Vader,,57701)
    Owner(owner,Sue,,57702)
    Owner(owner,Captain Kirk,,57702)
```